# How to save Spark Dataframe to Hana Vora table?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hana, vora

We have a file that we want split into 3 and that we need to perform some data cleanup on before it can be imported into Hana Vora - otherwise everything has to be typed as String, which is not ideal.

We can import and prepare the DataFrames in spark just fine, but then when i try to write to either the HDFS filesystem or, better, to save as a Table in the "com.sap.spark.vora" datasource, i get errors.

Can any one advise on a reliable way to import the spark-prepared datasets into Hana Vora? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Vora currently only officially supports appending data to an existing table (using the APPEND statement). For details see [SAP HANA Vora Developer Guide](http://help.sap.com/Download/Multimedia/hana_vora/SAP_HANA_Vora_Developer_Guide_en.pdf) -> Chapter "3.5 Appending Data to Existing Tables"

This means you would have to create an intermediate file. Vora supports reading from CSV, ORC, Parquet files. A dataframe can be saved in an ORC and Parquet files directly from Spark (see https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/sql-programming-guide.htm). To write to CSV files from Spark see https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv